# How to layout 1 row on left and 2 rows on right, in same vertical space, with Susy?

Tags: susy-compass

How can you implement the following layouts in Susy?

```
_________________________________
|              |   Rt. Top      |
|     Left     |________________|
|              |   Rt. Bottom   |
|______________|________________|
```

and its converse:

```
_________________________________
|   Lt. Top      |              |
|________________|    Right     |
|   Lt. Bottom   |              |
|________________|______________|
```

So far, for the top diagram, I tried:

```
  #header {
    #logo { @include span-columns( 4, 12); }
    #search { @include span-columns(8 omega,12 ); }
    #menu { @include span-columns(8 omega,12 ); }
  }

  <header id="header">
    <div id='logo'>logo logo logo logo<br>logo logo logo logo<br>logo logo logo logo<br>logo logo logo logo<br>logo logo logo logo<br>logo logo logo logo</div>
    <div id='search'>search search search<br>search search search<br>search search search<br>search search search<br>search search search<br>search search search</div>
    <div id='menu'>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu<br>menu menu menu</div>
  </header>
```

Which results in:

```
_________________________________
|              |                |
|     Left     |     Rt. Top    |
|______________|________________|
               |   Rt. Bottom   |
               |________________|
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Edited initial post with Sass & HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my example above worked OK, I just couldn't see that with the sample text.  For future reference, this worked for both the above.  Note the order of the HTML divs: bottom-left has to appear after sidebar-right.

```
  <header id="header">
<div id='logo'>logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo</div>
<div id='search'>search search search search search search search search search search search search search search search search search search</div>
<div id='menu'>menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu menu</div>

<div id='top-left'>top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top</div>
<div id='sidebar-right'>right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right right</div>
<div id='bottom-left'>bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom</div> </header>
```

Sass:

```
  #header {
#logo { @include span-columns( 4, 12); }
#search { @include span-columns(8 omega,12 ); }
#menu { @include span-columns(8 omega,12 ); }
#top-left { @include span-columns( 8, 12); }
#bottom-left { @include span-columns( 8, 12); }
#sidebar-right { @include span-columns(4 omega,12 ); } }
```

(bottom 2 lines of code in each ex. concatenated; appears to be a line limit of stackoverflow)